How to distinguish empty/null/unset array property in appsettings.json?
I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration in ASP.NET Core 9.0 to access configurations from the appsettings.json file:
public class MySettings
{
    public int? Foo { get; set; }
    public string[]? Bar{ get; set; }
}

appsettings.json:
{
    [...]
    "MySettings": {
        "Foo": 42,
        "Bar": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
        ]
    }
}

I'm reading this part this way:
var mySettings = config.GetSection("MySettings").Get<MySettings>();

This works well, mySettings.Bar is string[3] = ["a", "b", "c"] as you'd expect.
Now I'm having trouble to distinguish between three other cases in appsettings.json:
A:
{
    [...]
    "MySettings": {
        "Foo": 42
    }
}

B:
{
    [...]
    "MySettings": {
        "Foo": 42,
        "Bar": null
    }
}

C:
{
    [...]
    "MySettings": {
        "Foo": 42,
        "Bar": []
    }
}

For all three cases, mySettings.Bar will become null, but I'd want only A and B to become null, and C to become string[0].
I have found lots of little bits and ideas from a question for Newtonsoft Json.NET but I can't seem to figure out how to cram it all into something that works with Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration:

Default value [] for Bar, like also suggested here; that alone would break A and B though
MissingMemberHandling; not sure Include would lead to null overriding a default value; and does System.Text.Json even have anything like this?
NullValueHandling; same questions as for MissingMemberHandling
A custom converter for MySettings could maybe do it if keep the default to be null and get to take my own look at the JsonElement when the property is parsed; I don't know where to set JsonSerializerOptions for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Some attributes on Bar itself; but which? System.Text.Json doesn't have a lot to begin with

It is crucial for me to be able to differentiate between A and C. B should preferably become null since that's what the file says, but I could cope with that becoming string[0] as well, too.

See if using Option 2 in this post meets your needs. Then use public string[]? Bar { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();.

@Itallmakescents I'm not sure what's special about Option 2. Is Microsoft.Extensions.Options different from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration in handling arrays?

Appsettings are not being handled by json (de)serialization, but by the JsonConfigurationFileParser which uses custom parsing.
This JsonConfigurationFileParser has private built-in logic to set empty arrays to null; see source code on GitHub.

A possible solution to achieve your goal is to inspect the MySettings configuration section as a Dictionary<string, object>. When applicable, adjust the value of the Bar property on the mySettings instance returned from below statement that you are already using.
var mySettings = config.GetSection("MySettings").Get<MySettings>();


For scenario A, the TryGetValue method of the dictionary will return false.
For scenario B, the dictionary holds an empty string value for key Bar. This is also a rather unexpected behavior of the JsonConfigurationFileParser.



For scenario C, the value for dictionary entry with key Bar is null.


That gives below code, which checks whether the Bar key is present and whether the value is not an empty string. If so, either an array with values or an empty one has been configured and a possible nullvalue for property Bar needs to be replaced by an empty array.
var mySettings = config.GetSection("MySettings").Get<MySettings>();

var section = config.GetRequiredSection("MySettings").Get<Dictionary<string, object>>()!;
if (section.TryGetValue("Bar", out var value)
    && value is not string
    )
{
    mySettings.Bar ??= [];
}


This looks promising. Any idea how I can use this technique for nested objects, too?

I couldn't find a way to get this hooked in the internal handling of the framework, so for now I tend to say the closest thing one can achieve is a like custom helper method that uses some reflection to go over the settings class to look for collection/array properties and applies above.

Hm. Well it works for the top level object, so I'm going to accept it. For the different location I use Get<List<Repository>> (and Repository has a MySettings property with the same problem), so I think all I can do is to manually go through [0..n] and "carefully" deserialize one Repository after another.

Until the framework gets it fixed, I guess it will always be kind of a struggle; what matters is that I hear you have a way forward.

I don't think this can be "fixed" because it might break existing apps... Man I hate it when Microsoft code does "clever" conversions. Was a bad idea in Excel, still is a bad idea in JsonConfigurationFileParser hehe.

I am now using Get<List<Repository>>, then for loop through each index i, and if MySettings is not null && MySettings.Bar is null I get the section called $"{i}:MySettings" and use your technique to figure out if Bar is really missing or null or actually just a discarded []. Ugly that I have to do it, but it works and that's what matters.
